# i've confused myself with validation. I was trying to make a login/registry function and have found it hard to validate login details to my database

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to make a login/registry function using tkinter in python, but have confused myself with the validation through the login function. It should connect with the database and see if the fields are correct, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```py
def login_verify():
    global c

    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()

    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_login_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_login_entry.delete(0, END)

    finduser = ('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username =? AND password =?')
    c.execute(finduser,[(username1),(password1)])
    results = c.fetchall()
    if results:
        login_sucess()

    else:
        password_not_recognised()
        user_not_found()

def login_success():
    global login_success_screen
    login_success_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    login_success_screen.title("Success")
    login_success_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(login_success_screen, text="Login Success").pack()
    Button(login_success_screen, text="OK", command=delete_login_success).pack()

def password_not_recognised():
    global password_not_recog_screen
    password_not_recog_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    password_not_recog_screen.title("Success")
    password_not_recog_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(password_not_recog_screen, text="Invalid Password ").pack()
    Button(password_not_recog_screen, text="OK", command=delete_password_not_recognised).pack()


def user_not_found():
    global user_not_found_screen
    user_not_found_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    user_not_found_screen.title("Success")
    user_not_found_screen.geometry("150x100")
    Label(user_not_found_screen, text="User Not Found").pack()
    Button(user_not_found_screen, text="OK", command=delete_user_not_found_screen).pack()
```

when logging in with an incorrect password it should run the function 'password_not_recognised'

when logging in with details not in the database it should run 'user_not_found'

and when details are correct it should run login_success ()

Comment: Your current DB query cannot distinguish between "user not found" and "password incorrect" - both result in zero rows returned.  You could either do two queries (the first one on `username` alone), or change the query to `SELECT password FROM Users WHERE username=?` and compare the returned password yourself.  (Or just leave it like it is, and have a combined error message to cover both cases - lots of real-world logins work that way, to keep attackers from probing the valid usernames.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather give you the hook to accomplish this task yourself so I will cover the fundamentals:

- You've used prepared statements which is **great** and prevents sql injection attacks when used correctly. Although you should never store the passwords plaintext at your database. Use the `hashlib` module and compare the hash of the password to the hash of the password that is stored in the db.
- The username field should be a unique primary key, Thus only a single row in a table should ever contain a given username.

Two changes should be made to the way you query the database:

1. The sql query should not contain both the Username and the Password fields in the where statement. This is because you cannot determine if the query failed because the user does not exist or the password does not match
2. Use cursor.fetchone to fetch the user's row and store it in a variable. If it is not None the user exists and proceed to password validation.